# Handling clicks using ui-sref and inside elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

I'm designing a particular page where wherever I click I want to go back to the homepage.
All of the page in enclosed in a section:

```
<section id="test-page-1" ui-sref="project.home">
</section>
```

The problem is that I have 3 particular buttons in this page and are not working as they should, instead they are also redirecting me to the Home page. 
Z-index didn't solve the problem as from what I read it only works on a visual perspective rather than functionality. I'd really like it if I can still use the ui-sref="project.home" in the whole section as it is. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Any chance to provide more code or even a working demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the functions associated with you button clicks, stop the event propagation.

```js
$scope.buttonFunctioanlity = function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

```html
<button ng-click="buttonFunctioanlity($event)">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after !! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You know what ui-sref is right?
Changing your application state and redirecting to different url (Home in your case)

not really understood your problem, but remember you can add ng-click together with ui-sref to do some function before redirecting (might help your logic)

like

```
<section id="test-page-1" 
         ng-click="doSomething(someParams)" 
         ui-sref="project.home"></section>
```

and controller

```
$scope.doSomething = function(someParams) {
   // bla-bla-blaaa
}
```